# Efficient dataframe iteration in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a a 5 million row data frame, with two columns, as such (this data frame only has ten rows for simplicity):

```
df <- data.frame(start=c(11,21,31,41,42,54,61,63), end=c(20,30,40,50,51,63,70,72))
```

I want to be able to produce the following numbers in a numeric vector:

```
11 to 20, 21 to 30, 31 to 40, 41 to 50, 51, 54-63, 64-70, 71-72
```

And then take the length of the new vector (in this case, 10+10+10+10+1+10+7+2) = 60

*NOTE, I do not need the vector itself, just it's length will suffice. So if someone has a more intelligent logical approach to obtain the length, that is welcomed.

Essentially, what was done, was the for each row in the dataframe, the sequence from the start to end was taken, and all these sequences were combined, and then filtered for UNIQUE values.

So I used an approach as such:

```
length(unique(c(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    return(as.numeric(x[1]):as.numeric(x[2]))
}))))
```

which proves incredibly slow on my five million row data frame.

Any quicker more efficient solutions? Bonus, please try to add system time.

user  system elapsed 
 19.946   0.620  20.477

Comment: If you have 5 million rows of numeric data to begin with, you should be using a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`

Comment: Isn't the length of the new vector just the sum of the differences (plus 1)? `sum(df$end - df$start + 1)`?

Comment: @konvas; not quite as some starts are before the previous end

Comment: No, because there are overlaps. In the df data frame, the fourth row is 41-50, and the fifth row is 42-51. By your methodology, the total number of unique numbers would (50-41+1)+(51-42+1) = 20, whereas it should be 41-51, or (51-41+1) = 11.

Comment: @Richard Scriven Okay, even upon converting to matrix, there should still be faster ways. By the way, another part of the script I am writing had generated a data frame.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, assuming your data is sorted.

```
library(dplyr)  # for the lag function

with(df, sum(end - pmax(start, lag(end, 1, default = 0)+1) + 1))
#[1] 60

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  beginneR={with(df, sum(end - pmax(start, lag(end, 1, default = 0)+1) + 1))},
  r2evans={vec <- pmax(mm[,1], c(0,1+head(mm[,2],n=-1))); sum(mm[,2]-vec+1);},
  times = 1000
)

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq  median       uq       max neval
beginneR   37.398  41.4455  42.731  44.0795    74.349  1000
r2evans    31.788  35.2470  36.827  38.3925  9298.669  1000
```

So matrix is still faster, but not much (and the conversion step is still not included here). And I wonder why the max duration in @r2evans's answer is so high compared to all other values (which are really fast)

Comment: I saw the high max time, too. I ran it several times and saw that outlier pop up in both mine and yours, about an equal number of times. Perhaps we're seeing artifacts of inconveniently-timed garbage collection. *shrug*

Comment: For a more accurate benchmark it would be necessary to know more about the actual data anyway. Would be nice if the OP could provide some, though I won't be at my desk the next couple hours to test.

Comment: @beginneR Well, I'll give it to you. I find this interesting. I shall link the .RData file to Dropbox. Be forewarned, you might need some packages such as Biostrings (just do quick Google search on how to download), IRanges, BiocGenerics, parallel. So go ahead and run wild! And remember! You have to order it by start position first! https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5670r02jbyl9mx/data.RData. And, yeah, just use `load(file=)` and it will load as the variable original.data

Comment: @r2evans Well, I'll give it to you. I find this interesting. I shall link the .RData file to Dropbox. Be forewarned, you might need some packages such as Biostrings (just do quick Google search on how to download), IRanges, BiocGenerics, parallel. So go ahead and run wild! And remember! You have to order it by start position first! https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5670r02jbyl9mx/data.RData. And, yeah, just use `load(file=)` and it will load as the variable original.data

Comment: @user3855285, for some reason I wasn't able to load your data. Perhaps you can just go ahead and pick an answer to be accepted, since your question has been solved, right?

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
mm <- as.matrix(df) ## critical for performance/scalability
(vec <- pmax(mm[,1], c(0,1+head(mm[,2],n=-1))))
##  [1] 11 21 31 41 51 54 64 71
sum(mm[,2] - vec + 1)
##  [1] 60
```

(This should scale reasonable well, certainly better than data.frames.)

**Edit**: after I updated my code to use matrices and no `apply` calls, I did a quick benchmark of my implementation compared with the other answer (which is also correct):

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
microbenchmark(
    beginneR={
        df <- data.frame(start=c(11,21,31,41,42,54,61,63),
                         end=c(20,30,40,50,51,63,70,72))
        with(df, sum(end - pmax(start, lag(end, 1, default = 0)+1) + 1))
    },
    r2evans={
        mm <- matrix(c(11,21,31,41,42,54,61,63,
                       20,30,40,50,51,63,70,72), nc=2)
        vec <- pmax(mm[,1], c(0,1+head(mm[,2],n=-1)))
        sum(mm[,2]-vec+1)
    }
    )
##  Unit: microseconds
##       expr     min      lq   median      uq     max neval
##   beginneR 230.410 238.297 244.9015 261.228 443.574   100
##    r2evans  37.791  40.725  44.7620  47.880 147.124   100
```

This benefits greatly from the use of matrices instead of data.frames.

Oh, and system time is not that helpful here :-)

```
system.time({
    mm <- matrix(c(11,21,31,41,42,54,61,63,
                   20,30,40,50,51,63,70,72), nc=2)
    vec <- pmax(mm[,1], c(0,1+head(mm[,2],n=-1)))
    sum(mm[,2]-vec+1)
})
##     user  system elapsed 
##        0       0       0
```

Comment: Nice benchmark, though you didn't include `mm <- as.matrix(df)` in your function.

Comment: Good catch, but now that I include the formation of the data for all three, it still puts the `matrix` implementation ahead. Edit forthcoming ...

Comment: I don't think this is right, since the data is already in a data.frame, so no conversion (or creation) of a data.frame is required for my answer, while it is required to _convert_ the data.frame to matrix for your answer..

Comment: Funny, we're in a race to reduce our execution time ... if the data is already formed (your benchmark), there is now a mere 25% speed improvement with using matrices over data.frames -- I'm impressed and surprised (`dplyr` is truly magic).

Comment: I'm not sure this has too much to do with `dplyr` itself

Comment: Anyway, your soulution is very nice as well +1

Comment: You're not wrong, but we are "assuming" that the data is originally formed in a data.frame. We need @user3855285 to weigh in on the formation of the data. Your point is well taken, though, which is why I think both of our benchmark results are informative.

Comment: See one of the OP's comments to Richard, he says his data is generated in a data.frame

Comment: True (and I had originally read but forgot about that comment), but not seeing all of his code, perhaps it was not necessary to produce a data.frame in the first place, a mistake I've made numerous times. Moot point, don't know. Dead horse beaten.

Comment: Well, if I may comment, to settle this, I am using a package called Biostrings in conjunction with a package called BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19, and BSgenome itself. Basically, in a nutshell, I am looking for certain genome base sequences (like "ACGT") in the genome. The function they provide to find these sequences is `matchPDict()` and I use it as such: `matchPDict(PDict(c("AGCT", "AGCA", "TGCA", "TGCT", "TCGA", "TCGT", "ACGT", "ACGA")), Hsapiens$chr1)`. This returns a list. I simply convert to data frame, using as.data.frame since there are both character and numeric vectors in the list.